Power in dBm for IoT
Let's assume a bandwidth $B=100$ kHz and the transmit power is set to $P=14$ dBm.
If I use a waveform with a $PAPR \simeq 10$ dB, is communication possible? And how will a high PAPR penalize the battery life?


If I use a waveform with a PAPR≃10 dB, is communication possible?

Sure, nothing about PAPR alone puts any theoretical boundaries on communication.

And how will a high PAPR penalize the battery life?

Impossible to tell – battery life is a result of analog and digital system design, and far too many factors come in to play here. PAPR, together with a measure on acceptable distortion, certainly puts bounds on the theoretical efficiency a certain type of amplifier might achieve, but a) you're not using a theoretical type of amplifier, but a choice of practical ones,  and b) PAPR reduction comes with other trade-offs, which themselves might de- or increase power draws.
All in all, your question tries to reduce a communication system to a single property, PAPR, and that property is really very secondary in almost all aspects, especially if it's not a very high value. A 10 dB PAPR is very very benign – even a very boring 16 QAM system with pulse shaping routinely exceeds that.
